# Functions questions about how to find independent and dependant variable

Tags: functions

I don't really get this question, I'm familiar with the basic concepts of turning equations into functions. But this one is worded in a way I am not too sure about.

If a rectangle has area $100 m^2$ and sides $l$ and $b$, then $lb = 100$. Write this formula as a function with

a) $l$ as the independent variable.

b) $l$ as the dependent variable.

What does it mean by finding Independent and dependent variable? And how do I solve for each? Especially for non worded equations.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a) you write $b$ as  function of $l$: $b=\frac {100} l$.

In b) you write $l$ as  function of $b$: $l=\frac {100} b$.